# Bounding the probabilty $P\{\underset{1 \leq i< j \leq N}{min} \rho(X_i,X_j)\leq x \}$

Tags: probability

Independent random variables $X_1,. . . , X_N$ are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]^2$.
How to determine any nontrivial bounds on the probability: $P\{\underset{1 \leq i< j \leq N}{min} \rho(X_i,X_j)\leq x \}$, where $\rho(x,y)$ is euclidean metrics?

I tried to bound this probability by using "Bonferroni's inequality" but nothing nontrivial it has given.

Comment: You may use $d$ instead of $\rho$, which is commonly used for the correlation coefficient. Could you add some of your efforts? For example, for the simple case of $n=2$.